# Устанавливать страну/город пользователя на PHP c помощью ресурса http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=

Tags: php, ip

Нужно на серверной стороне (на PHP) устанавливать страну (и город) пользователя, чтоб в зависимости от этого отображать ему тот или иной контент.

Нашел ресурс (http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=) и судя по описанию хороший, обновляемый. Нигде не нашел как правильно с  ним работать и можно ли его применить в моем  случае. Все, что мне нужно,подставить в этот URL  IP-адрес пришедшего Юзера и потом забрать данные которые на этом ресурсе в виде XML.

Я прописал у себя такой скрипт:

```
function get_city_by_ip($ip) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip='.$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $city = ( !curl_errno($ch) && $xml = simplexml_load_string($data) ) ? $xml->ip->city : false;
    curl_close($ch);

    return $city;
}

var_dump( get_city_by_ip( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) );
```

Но контента с этого ресурса я не получаю. Получаю

```
bool(false)
```

Что я не верно делаю или забыл прописать?
Возможно есть и другие способы подучать страну пользователя, но мне нужны именно такие внешние русурсы, куда бы я мог отправить curlи получить данные, устанавливать себе базу дополнительную и библиотеки в моем случае не вариант.

Comment: Могу подсказать, что страну можно определять в своём веб-сервере - гуглить по nginx, geoip. Точность не факт, что будет космическая, зато работает практически из коробки

Comment: Касательно отладки - можно курл погонять из консоли, чтобы понять вообще в чем проблема - в API сайта, в курле или в php. А затем уже интегрировать код. Ну, и обычно сторонние сервисы требуют токена (авторизацию, короче). По настоящему бесплатных сервисов уже и нет....

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример функции для этого сервиса.

```
function get_city_by_ip($ip)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=' . 
  $ip);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $ip_answer = simplexml_load_string($data);

  $city = ($ip_answer -> ip[0] -> city);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $city;
}
```

Было бы удобнее если бы он выдавал json.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у Вас работает на данный момент такой код? 
Я заменил свою функцию Вашей, потом прописал, чтоб видеть результат:

$city = get_city_by_ip( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
var_dump( $city );


и у меня выдает NULL.  
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что вы используете в качестве Http сервера? Возможно ваш сервер неправильно выдает REMOTE ADDR. попробуйте выполнить echo  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: У меня тот код функции которую я указал, плюс кодировка выводило тот скриншот в ответе

Comment: вот как раз $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; выдает корректный IP адрес, - с этим все норм. Поскольку я этот IP адрес потом вставляю в ресурс http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=   
и мне данный сервис совершенно корректно и конкретно указывает все данные. 
Проблема в чем-то ином. Может действительно сам сервер на котором расположен сайт имеет какие-то доп.ограничения.  не знаю.

Comment: Может быть, скрипт не имеет доступа к интернету... Попробуйте вывести переменную $data после выполнения `$data = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: Да, вывел  $data  сразу после строки $data = curl_exec($ch); 
выдало - bool(false)

Comment: тогда попробуйте сделать `if ($ch === false) echo "initialization";` после инициализации `$ch = curl_init();`. Может быть что-то с ней случилось.